# Arrow keys change pics Javascript

Tags: javascript

When you click the thumbnail picture, It will show the bigger picture then you can use arrow keys (left and right) to change a prev/next pic.

I don't know how to code for the right arrow key to avoid NaN value.

It will output NaN value when you keep pressing the right arrow key. How can I avoid that? How can I expect the value 1,2,3,4,.... when I keep pressing the right arrow key? here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="5" data-toggle="modal" data-title="Breast Revision Implant Exchange" data-caption="Before and After: Previous breast implants removed and exchanged with larger smooth round silcone implants followed by liposuction of the armpit/axillary and side of chest area" data-image="http://www.afbplasticsurgery.com/before-after-images/breast-revision-lateral-view-b-a.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
    <div class="ba-thumb">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="ba-thumbnail" src="http://www.afbplasticsurgery.com/before-after-images/thumb/breast-revision-b-lateral-view-150.jpg"></td>
            <td><img class="ba-thumbnail" src="http://www.afbplasticsurgery.com/before-after-images/thumb/breast-revision-a-lateral-view-150.jpg"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="ba-note" colspan="2">Breast Revision Implant Exchange</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </a></div>
  <div class="clr"></div>

  <!-- end pic element -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <center>
            <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
          </center>
          <div class="modal-body-button">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <span id="show-previous-image" class="previous-page"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <span class="pull-right">
                <span id="show-next-image" class="next-page"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">This text will be overwritten by jQuery </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

loadGallery(true, 'a.thumbnail');

function disableButtons(counter_max, counter_current) {
    $('#show-previous-image, #show-next-image').show();
    if (counter_max == counter_current) {
        $('#show-next-image').hide();
    } else if (counter_current == 1) {
        $('#show-previous-image').hide();
    }
}
function loadGallery(setIDs, setClickAttr) {
    var current_image, selector, counter = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        switch (code) {
            case 37:
                if (current_image == 1) {
                    current_image = 1;
                } else {
                    current_image--;
                }

                console.log(current_image);

                break;

            case 39:

                current_image++;
                console.log(current_image);
                break;

            default:
                return;

        }

        selector = $('[data-image-id="' + current_image + '"]');
        updateGallery(selector);

        e.preventDefault();

    });

    $('#show-next-image, #show-previous-image').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'show-previous-image') {
            current_image--;
        } else {
            current_image++;
        }

        selector = $('[data-image-id="' + current_image + '"]');
        updateGallery(selector);
        console.log(selector);
    });

    function updateGallery(selector) {
        var $sel = selector;
        current_image = $sel.data('image-id');
        $('#image-gallery-caption').text($sel.data('caption'));
        $('#image-gallery-title').text($sel.data('title'));
        $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
        disableButtons(counter, $sel.data('image-id'));
    }
    if (setIDs == true) {
        $('[data-image-id]').each(function() {
            counter++;
            $(this).attr('data-image-id', counter);
        });
    }
    $(setClickAttr).on('click', function() {
        updateGallery($(this));
    });
}
```

});

or take a look on http://jsfiddle.net/8o0L4e2f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i'm leaving my previous answer since all the issues I identified there are valid. however the code is too broken to continue fixing issue by issue. I was quite bored and decided to fix everything...

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o0L4e2f/1/), and the fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initial and max value of 0
    var current = 0, max = 0;

    // load up the gallery
    loadGallery(true, 'a.thumbnail');

    function navigate(forward) {
        if (forward && current <= max) {
            current++;
        } else if (current >= 1) {
            current--;
        }

        console.log('showing ' + current + 'th image');
        updateDetails();
        disableButtons();
    }

    function updateDetails() {
        console.log('updating details for ' + current + 'th image');
        var $sel = $('[data-image-id="' + current + '"]');
        $('#image-gallery-caption').text($sel.data('caption'));
        $('#image-gallery-title').text($sel.data('title'));
        $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
        $('#image-gallery-link a').text($sel.data('title'));
        $('#image-gallery-link a').attr('src', $sel.data('href'));
    }

    function disableButtons() {
        console.log('in disable, (current=' + current + ', max=' + max + ')');
        if (current == max) {
            console.log('disabling next');
            $('#show-next-image').hide();
            $('#show-previous-image').show();
        } else if (current == 0) {
            console.log('disabling previous');
            $('#show-next-image').show();
            $('#show-previous-image').hide();
        }
    }

    // loads the gallery and sets observers
    function loadGallery(setIDs, setClickAttr) {
        if (setIDs) {
            $('[data-image-id]').each(function(i, e) {
                console.log('setting id for image: ' + i);
                $(this).attr('data-image-id', (max = i));
            });
        }

        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            e.preventDefault();

            switch (code) {
                // left key
                case 37: navigate(false); break;
                // right key
                case 39: navigate(true); break; 
                default:;
            }
        });

        $('#show-next-image, #show-previous-image').click(function () {
            navigate($(this).attr('id') === 'show-next-image');
        });

        $(setClickAttr).on('click', function() {
            current = $(this).attr('data-image-id');
            console.log('clicked the ' + current + 'th image...');
            updateDetails();
            disableButtons();
        });
    }
});
```

<sub>PS: if you just went through with a debugger, you would have been able to fix it as well.</sub>

Comment: did you get to check this out?

Comment: I just did, It works perfectly Thanks so much @epoch !!

Comment: I just did accept I cannot vote. This was my first time in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `current_image` variable is never initialized. You have this:

```
var current_image
```

It is the same as:

```
var current_image = undefined;
```

So when your code runs the first time, `current_image` is not equal to one, and thus your code tries to decrement it:

```
if (current_image == 1) {
    current_image = 1;
} else {
    current_image--;
}
```

Decrementing `undefined` will give you `NaN`:

[image]

So to fix this, you need to have a start value for your `current_image` variable.

ex: `var current_image = 0;`

**UPDATE**

Ok, so after looking at it again, you assign your `current_image` variable in multiple places.

after you press <kbd>right</kbd> the `current_image` value gets incremented, and then `updateGallery` gets called, in this function the following line is run; this is where it gets the `undefined` value:

```
current_image = $sel.data('image-id');
```

which means, the image-id is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Epoch for quick respond. I started value for current_image already

var current_image, selector, counter = 0;

This is a link if you dont mind to take a look.
http://www.afbplasticsurgery.com/breast-revision-images/

I appreciate that

Comment: It only happened when we keep pressing the right arrow key

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this

current_image = $sel.data('image-id');

Thanks Epoch!

Comment: Im sorry to ask you again, how can I fix that? I haven't figured it out